# Отладка в gdb под Linux

Tags: linux, c, ассемблер, gdb

Совсем недавно начал изучать реверс. И вот, выполняя одно из тестовых заданий на stack-based buffer overflow, столкнулся с одной непонятной мне проблемой.

Есть программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[256];
    memcpy(buf, argv[1],strlen(argv[1]));
    printf(buf);
}
```

Отладчик использую gdb. Проблемка вылезает в момент, когда я пытаюсь работать с адресами и выглядит она так:

```
   0x00001216 <+77>:    call   0x1050 <memcpy@plt>
   0x0000121b <+82>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x0000121e <+85>:    sub    $0xc,%esp
   0x00001221 <+88>:    lea    -0x118(%ebp),%eax
   0x00001227 <+94>:    push   %eax
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
   0x00001228 <+95>:    call   0x1040 <printf@plt>
   0x0000122d <+100>:   add    $0x10,%esp
   0x00001230 <+103>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00001235 <+108>:   lea    -0xc(%ebp),%esp
   0x00001238 <+111>:   pop    %ecx
   0x00001239 <+112>:   pop    %ebx
   0x0000123a <+113>:   pop    %esi
   0x0000123b <+114>:   pop    %ebp
   0x0000123c <+115>:   lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
   0x0000123f <+118>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *main+77
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1216
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x00001216 <main+77>
(gdb) r AAA
Starting program: /root/Documents/stackoverflow/charBuf256x32 AAA

Breakpoint 1, 0x56556216 in main ()
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x56556216 <main+77>
    breakpoint already hit 1 time
(gdb)
```

Собственно, вопрос: что это за 5-ки, которые внезапно появляются **в адресе точки останова**? 
ДО запуска программы:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1216
```

ПОСЛЕ запуска программы:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x56556216 in main ()
```

Почему адреса всё же несколько схожи(только часть адреса заменяется 5-ками). Смею предположить, что вопрос несколько некомпетентен, а ответ удивительно лёгок, но самому мне его найти не удалось.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Исправил. Добавил текстом

Comment: Вы о чём? Какие пятёрки?

Comment: В начале, когда я ставлю точку останова по адресу main+76, то брейк устанавливается по адресу  
**Breakpoint 1 at 0x1216**
После запуска программы брейк уже находится по адресу:  
**Breakpoint 1, 0x56556216 in main ()**

Comment: а «пятёрки» — это [рандомизация адресного пространства](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR) после запуска, если что.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо тем, кто учавстовал. Проблема решилась, можно сказать, сама по себе. 
Ответом был запуск программы на машине с х32 архитектурой, до этого — х64. В таких условиях "моя" проблема больше не наблюдалась